# Please help with Stock/Custom Rom for Bluboo s8a

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, stock-rom, flashtool

I was trying to root bluboo s8a with TWRP following this [tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/rooting-roms/root-tutorial-bluboo-s8-twrp-t3699724/amp/)
When I reached step 2 of installing the ROM with sp flash tools, the ROM installed up to the end but the phone stopped powering (doesn't show anything). I tried downloading other customs ROMs for bluboo s8 but they were customized to be flashed with TWRP because they had no scatter files.

I landed on one custom ROM which I flashed into the phone with sp flash tools and the phone powered on and I could hear the sound when I press the buttons and when the phone is powering on but the screen shows a dark screen.

I would like to go back to the stock ROM or a working custom ROM. I took some screenshots of the settings of the About Phone before trying the rooting process.

[image] [image]
<sup>About Phone (click images for larger variants)</sup>

**Update:** Now I have gotten some ROM from the seller's website. It's in a zip file with one .cpb file and a folder named dbs. The folder has two files. When I try flashing the .cpb file with QGDP, I get an error of `CPB Package is not complete`. How can I overcome this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got another ROM version which was extracted into .img files to use sp flash tools. I flashed the ROM with sp flash tools and the phone worked again.

Tools needed:

1. Sp flash Tool
2. Firmware

The link to the stock firmware/ stock ROM file for BLUBOO S8a _V27.20180314 is [here](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/DN1u/6WNnvh37S)

ps: credit goes to Rusya77@ Ruslan N and Samin Sikong